# Agglomerative clustering algorithm that preserves ordering of the data points?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I need a hierarchical clustering implementation (preferably in matlab) that preserves the order of my data points. For example, I don't want it to output something like this

```
(((1, 5), (2, 3)), 4)
```

I pretty sure that there is a better term for this. I just need it to combine the clusters are near each other in the same order as the input.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it yourself? It's not particularly hard, and I don't think this aligns with the intuition of cluster analysis.

Comment: Ok. Let's say I have a video and I like to segment the video in time based on the differences between frames. Then I don't want to group non-contiguous segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is **no longer cluster-analysis**. It's similar, but not clustering.

You are trying to *segment* your data, i.e. you actually have a given sequence and look for good points to *split* it.

In the usual way of thinking in cluster analysis, you have lots of individual items, and you want to *collect* these so that nearby objects are aggregated; in a way that they **may or may not** be contiguous.

Really, instead of trying to hack a clustering algorithm to achieve your goals, it makes just *tons* more sense to start from your starting point, and just maybe "reuse" some of the ideas that were previously used in clustering.

The reason is not just technical, but also a matter of *intuition*.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. I was just checking whether such an implementation exists. Not to create wheels from scratch.

Comment: You might be able to use Generalized DBSCAN though. In the generalized version, you could specify the predefined order as "neighbors", and then e.g. use low variances as core point predicate.